# How to map from one container into another w/Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, clojure, java-stream

So, in Clojure, I can just say something like this...

```
(into [] (map some-function some-collection))
```

And I get a new vector of my transformed data.

Is there some *simple* equivalent of `into` for Java 8 streams? For example, I don't see a constructor on `ArrayList` that takes a stream, nor do I see some sort of helper function in `java.util.Collections`, nor the stream interface.

Comment: Never wrote Clojure, but it seems you just want `someCollection.stream().map(someFunction).collect(Collectors.toList())`?

Comment: For arrays you can use `.toArray();`

Comment: ... which is hard to workout from the Javadoc alone, but there is a large number of examples and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html):

```
someCollection.stream()
              .map(someFunction)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can do other cool stuff with Collectors, as explained in its javadoc:

```
 Map<Department, Integer> totalByDept =
     employees.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,
                                               Collectors.summingInt(Employee::getSalary)));
```